# Extract spesific date in string regex

Tags: regex

I have following string

```
Документ подписан аналогом собственноручной подписи Клиента (простой электронной подписью): [349522252]
[01.12.2019][8605]
Дата подписания: 01.12.2019
```

I need to extract date so result should be `01.12.2019`. I fugured out how to extract something between `[...]`

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])
```

but it's captured wrong [image]

Comment: `(?<=\[)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}(?=\])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\[)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?=\])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/osJp4M/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `[` char
  -`\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{1,2}\.`  - one or two digits and a dot
- `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` - two or four digits
- `(?=\])`  - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `]` char.